# Problem connecting a deployed smart contract to JavaScript. Remix + JS + Infura + Ropsten (with Metamask)

Tags: web3js, remix, javascript, ropsten, infura

I am a beginner in DApps and still learning most concepts. Recently, I wrote a smart contract in Remix IDE which I deployed in the ropsten test network using injected web3 and metamask. The functions in the contract works fine and as expected. Here is the contract:

```
pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;

contract details {
    uint count=0;
   struct empDetails {
        uint date;
        string bank;
        uint BPay;
        uint allw;
        uint spallw;
        string status;
    }
    mapping (string => empDetails) AllDetails;


    function SetUserInfo(uint _date, string memory _empID, string memory _bank, string memory _status,
    uint _BPay, uint _allw, uint _spallw) public {
        AllDetails[_empID].date = _date;
        AllDetails[_empID].bank = _bank;
        AllDetails[_empID].BPay = _BPay;
        AllDetails[_empID].allw = _allw;
        AllDetails[_empID].spallw = _spallw;
        AllDetails[_empID].status = _status;
}


    function GetUserInfo(string memory _empID) public view returns (uint,string memory,uint,uint,uint,string memory)
    {
        return (AllDetails[_empID].date,AllDetails[_empID].bank,AllDetails[_empID].BPay, AllDetails[_empID].allw,
        AllDetails[_empID].spallw,AllDetails[_empID].status);
    }

}
```

I tried connecting it using web3 to a simple frontend that I am creating. Before using Ropsten, I tried deploying it on Ganache client and it worked fine. When executing the same code in Ropsten, I faced a lot of errors which I solved using other posts in this forum as reference. Here is the final code:

```
const Web3 = require("web3");
const Tx= require("ethereumjs-tx").Transaction;

web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("https://ropsten.infura.io/v3/MY_ROPSTEN_API"));
  
var UserContract = new web3.eth.Contract(ABI, CONTRACT_ADDRESS);

var privatekey= new Buffer.from(PRIVATE_KEY, 'hex');

async function Submit(){

const myData= UserContract.methods.SetUserInfo(144447,"E102","ASBI","Working",30000,4060,5020).encodeABI();
const mynonce = await web3.utils.toHex(web3.eth.getTransactionCount(ACCOUNT_ADDRESS)) 
const txObject={from:ACCOUNT_ADDRESS,
gasPrice:100,
gasLimit:gasLimitHex = 300000,
nonce:mynonce,data:myData};

var tx= new Tx(txObject,{'chain':'ropsten'});
tx.sign(privatekey);
const serializedTx= tx.serialize();
const raw='0x'+serializedTx.toString('hex');
const transaction=web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(raw,(err,txr)=>{
    
    if(err)
    {
        console.log(err);
    }
    else{
        console.log("It is Working "+txr);
    }
})

}
Submit();
```

I have only hardcoded the input parameter values for now. When I try running the Submit() function, I am getting a success message "It is Working" along with some other value which I am assuming is the transaction hash.

Sample Output:
It is Working 0x39418c22fc32c1670fcad9f9eba991976434b64bcf8a8ba0cf49ee1799efa90a

But I don't see any changes in Metamask or on Etherscan. I also tried running the getter function in the solidity contract using remix's own environment on the data that I hardcoded, but I am only getting a set of empty values.
Can someone help me understand what's going on and what I'm doing wrong?